# Android How do I write a simple timer for UI events?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, double-click

My app needs to check whether user double clicks or not. But I can't use Android OnDoubleClickListener or something likes that. Just implements it :

My problem is diferent from "normal" double click.

What I want is:
If user double clicks, run the Y activity.
If user clicks 1 click only, wait 500 ms then run the X activity.
If user click 2 click slowly, run the X activity

This is my code:

```
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        thisTime = now;

        if (thisTime - lastTouchTime < WAIT_TIME) {
            // Double tap

            this.getContext()
                    .getApplicationContext()
                    .startActivity(
                            (new Intent(getContext(),
                                    ChangePlaceActivity.class))
                                    .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));

            // If is double tap, reset to start state.
            lastTouchTime = -1;
            return true;
        } else {
            // Too slow or first click
            // If not double tap, save last state for next check

            lastTouchTime = thisTime;

            Log.d("Worker thread", "Declare" + System.currentTimeMillis());
            Thread t = new Thread() {
                public void run()
                {
                    try {
                        sleep(WAIT_TIME);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            t.start();
            try {
                t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("Worker thread", "" + System.currentTimeMillis());

            // start MainAct
            Log.d("Single Click", "Yes");
            this.getContext()
                    .getApplicationContext()
                    .startActivity(
                            (new Intent(getContext(),

                            MainActivity.class))
                                    .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
        }
```

If use code like this, I can't got double click. If remove thread.run() thread.join(). It will start MainActivity before ChangePlacecActivity.

Is there any solution for this problems?
Thank you in advance!

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Why don't you start a timer after the first tap. If youre already tracking a tap and get another before the timer fires, run your double tap code. If the timer fires first, run your X code. This is the way that event driven UI works. Please never, ever call sleep, especially on the UI thread.

Comment: @Jason Coco: I know that shouldn't block UI thread. A timer is what I need but dont' know to how. Please give the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head how to write a timer in Android. I suggest you edit your question and name it "How do I write a simple timer for UI events?". You can leave the rest of the question as is and leave these comments. I'm sure you'll get an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) for this.  Something like:

(class-level declarations)

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable singleClickTask = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    //run X activity
    firstClick = true;
  }
};
boolean firstClick = true;
```

(and then in onClick)

```
if (firstClick) {
  handler.postDelayed(singleClickTask, 500);
  firstClick=false;
} else {
  handler.removeCallbacks(singleClickTask);
  firstClick=true;
  //run Y activity
}
```

Please debug this yourself before using it blindly, but I think it's right.

Comment: thank you, I tried handler.postDelayed() but I didn't know   handler.removeCallbacks();